# Use one cell to hold File reference

Tags: excel, excel-2007

Hi I have a sheet with links to external workbooks, an example of a cell formula would be:

```
='C:\[Workbook1.xls]Sheet2'!M59
```

Everytime i change external workbook I have to change all the references in all of the cells. What I want to do is store the filereference in cell A1 like:

```
A1 would be C:\Workbook1.xls
```

And the rest of the cells in the sheet gets their targetfile from this cell... Then I could just change the fileref and update links and the data shown in the sheet would point to the new external workbook. Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do it:

```
=INDIRECT("'"&LEFT(A1,3)&"["&RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-3)&"]Sheet2'!M59")
```

Comment: Hmm, getting #ref error msg on this..  

A1 path = C:\Local\test.xls   

formula: =INDIRECT(LEFT(A1;9)&"["&RIGHT(A1;LEN(A1)-9)&"]Sheet1'!M59")

Comment: You've changed the 3 to 9. What the "LEFT" bit does it to separate out the C:\ from the rest so I can put a [ in. Does it work if you put 3 in instead of 9?

Comment: the result of the the formula inside indirect is: C:\Local\[test.xls]Sheet1'!M59

Comment: What's in A1? I see why you're using 9, but that should give you c:\local\[test.xls] etc.

Comment: inside A1: C:\Local\test.xls
Result of inner function without the rest of the concatination: C:\Local\[test.xls]

Comment: the \ before [test.xls] is gone in the above comment... for some reason it wont show up when I comment..

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake in the formula, and I've fixed it above. (I was missing a single quote at the start.)

Comment: Giving you the 'correct answer' tag, your formula works, thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

you seem to be introducing extra complexity with having different workbook names, can u leave the workbook name constant?

if you can't then you can use INDIRECT function to convert text into actual function calls.

Might also help if you use named Ranges (so that if cell location changes in the other workbook, it will still work)

Comment: I have 100 source workbooks I need to get information from(they all follow the same patterns), and Im makin 100 sheets in the destination workbook. So I made one template sheet to use for the 100 sheets. I was hoping i could just change A1 in each of the 100 sheets

Comment: then you are stuck with "INDIRECT" i think. how about havig Little VBA that opens each workbook, gets the data it needs and closes it down. that way you dont have to maintain links